# In ActionScript3 runtime, is there a way to get a list of all static members from a Class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Let's say we have following class

```
public class PlayerEvent extends Event
{
    public static const PLAYER_INIT:String = "playerInit";
    public static const PLAYER_MOVE:String = "playerMove";
    public static const PLAYER_USE_SKILL:String = "playerUseSkill";

    public function PlayerEvent(type:String)
    {
        super(type, false, true);
    }
}

}
```

In Flash Player runtime, is there a way I can get a list of all the static members of lass PlayerEvent.

Something like:

```
trace(PlayerEvent.staticMethods) // ["PLAYER_INIT", "PLAYER_MOVE", "PLAYER_USE_SKILL"]...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [`flash.utils::describeType`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29).